# How can I use complex control flow, arithmetic or functional primitives in the C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I would like to be able to write preprocessor macros using a more fully fledged language. Such a language would ideally include the following features:

- boolean and natural arithmetic and comparisons
- branching based on comparisons
- list representation
- recursion
- variable binding
- functions as first class values and higher order functions
- partial function application and currying
- functional primitives, such as `map` and `fold`
- useful functions/structures for common code generation tasks

Is this possible to implement within the C preprocessor?

Comment: You are probably better writing some code in a scripting language to output the (probably limited amount of) C code that needs complex construction.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Incredibly, the answer is yes! The [Order](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Order) header-only library provides a set of macros that implement a functional language inside the C preprocessor. It includes all of the specified features and more. You can use it as long as your C preprocessor is nearly completely C99 compliant. The GNU CPP (as used in GCC and G++) is compatible, as is the Boost Wave preprocessor. Order has been around since 2004. Although it is no longer maintained, it is very full featured, if not fully documented.

Here is a simple example use of Order:

```
#define AVERAGE(...) ((ORDER_PP( \
    8seq_for_each_with_delimiter( \
    8put, \
    8emit(8quote(+)), \
    8tuple_to_seq(8quote((__VA_ARGS__)))))) / \
    ORDER_PP(8to_lit(8tuple_size(8quote((__VA_ARGS__))))))
```

The macro `AVERAGE` expands to an expression expressing the mean of the provided arguments. `AVERAGE(a, b, c)` (for example) expands to `((a + b + c) / 3)`. This is a very simple example that does not use all of Order's features.

Another simple example, showing use of pre-compilation arithmetic (using an arbitrary precision natural number representation), functions as first class values (see the use of `8plus`) and variable binding, is a macro for computing (integer arithmetic) averages in the preprocessor:

```
#define AVERAGE_LITERAL(...) ORDER_PP(\
    8let((8A, 8quote((__VA_ARGS__))), \
    8to_lit(8quotient( \
    8seq_fold(8plus, 0, 8tuple_to_seq(8A)), \
    8tuple_size(8A)))))
```

`AVERAGE_LITERAL(5, 6, 8, 9)` expands to `7`.

I have only touched upon a few of the features. More practical examples are provided in the accompanying documentation and tutorial, including those showing how Order can help remove practically all tedious code repetition.

Order is very powerful, and it is still very relevant to C++ programmers - templates and inlining can only solve some problems. Order solves most of the others. The only inherent limitations I can find are the inability to manipulate string literals or manipulate tokens in any way other than replacing or concatenating, as this is imposed by the C preprocessor.

Comment: In C++, `constexpr` solves most of the others too. But the disjunction of the problems solved by Order and the problems solved by `constexpr` functions is probably quite interesting.

Comment: That disjunction is quite interesting, and quite large, in fact all repetitive-but-not-quite-identical code that can't be templated. There's a very good example in the Order docs about generating mathematical operator functions for a templated numerical array class. The example implements correct type promotion for operators involving different template instantiations of arrays, e.g. adding an Array<int> to an Array<long> gives an Array<long>, etc.

Comment: `template <typename T, typename U> auto operator+(const Array<T> &lhs, const Array<U> &rhs) -> Array<decltype(declval<T>() + declval<U>())>;`. I expect all the most compelling examples that were considered in writing Order were also at least considered in writing C++11. But I take your point, Order is flexible :-)

Comment: But the Order example makes several of those declarations. You've still got to write out the templated declaration for each operator with that approach. The main advantage Order holds over adding language features like that is that because it works by manipulating tokens it is not limited to solving problems that have been thought of by the standards committee.

Comment: Plus Order is available where C++11 isn't, by supplanting a non-compliant preprocessor with Boost Wave. So now I can write programs compatible with the VC++ ABI (MinGW is not an option) whilst not being so limited by poor standards compliance in VC++.